# apt-get CUDA installation appears to do nothing

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda

I am looking for a way to install the CUDA toolkit **without** the use of a `.run` installer from nvidia's website. I tried this before (and it installed successfully), however it caused havoc every time the kernel updated. I was advised by multiple sources to revert to an earlier backup and install CUDA again, using the package manager route.

***ATTEMPT 1***

So far, I have followed all the instructions at http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#axzz3zypHweWG Chapter 3.6 - Ubuntu Package Manager Installation.

After several pre-installation checks, you are supposed to use the package manager to install a rather large .deb file from the nvidia website (or equivalently use a lightweight network-based .deb installer).

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-<distro>_<version>_<architecture>.deb
```

The documentation informs us that:

> When using RPM or Deb, the downloaded package is a repository package. Such a package only informs the package manager where to find the actual installation packages, but will not install them.

Therefore, we complete the installation with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cuda
```

However apt-get *very quickly zipped through* the "install cuda" part in a second or so, displaying some banalities about the terms of use, then terminated without errors. However there were no signs of the CUDA toolkit having been installed.

For instance, I couldn't continue to setting the environment variables:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
```

because `/usr/local/cuda-7.5` was never created.

***ATTEMPT 2***

Having run `sudo apt-get purge cuda`, I saw that some people had used

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit
```

with better results. Asking for the `nvcc -version` command also suggests downloading this package.

This ran for a little while longer, which was reassuring. However after installation there was still no such directory as `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/`

Am I missing something obvious, or is this package manager method totally ineffectual?

Comment: This happens for me as well.